# laravel fetch query skip data with column if condition

Tags: mysql, laravel

here is a query for fetch data from DB

```
 $subcatgeory = DB::table('subategories')->where('category_id',$item->id)->get();
```

in a subcategory, there is a column name for `subcategory_En` values are look like this

| subcategory_En |
| --- |
| sample data |
| sample data 2 |
| unassign |

i want to skip when the `subcategory_En` column value is `unassign` and fetch other data

so I try this query

```
$subcatgeory = DB::table('subategories')->where('category_id',$item->id)->skip('subcategory_En','unassign')->get();
```

this query is not working how can I fetch data and skip with column values?

Comment: yep its work add this as an answer ill mark as answered really thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a second where clause.

```
$subcatgeory = DB::table('subategories')->where('category_id',$item->id)->where('subcategory_En', '!=', 'unassign')->get();
```

Skip is for limits and offsets.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#limit-and-offset